# Pandas DataFrame Calculate time difference between 2 columns on specific time range

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to calculate time difference between two columns on specific time range.

I try `df.between_time` but it only works on index.

Ex. Time range: between 18.00 - 8.00

Data :

```
             start               stop
0   2018-07-16 16:00:00  2018-07-16 20:00:00
1   2018-07-11 08:03:00  2018-07-11 12:03:00
2   2018-07-13 17:54:00  2018-07-13 21:54:00
3   2018-07-14 13:09:00  2018-07-14 17:09:00
4   2018-07-20 00:21:00  2018-07-20 04:21:00
5   2018-07-20 17:00:00  2018-07-21 09:00:00
```

Expect Result :

```
          start                  stop           time_diff
0   2018-07-16 16:00:00  2018-07-16 20:00:00    02:00:00
1   2018-07-11 08:03:00  2018-07-11 12:03:00    0
2   2018-07-13 17:54:00  2018-07-13 21:54:00    03:54:00
3   2018-07-14 13:09:00  2018-07-14 17:09:00    0
4   2018-07-20 00:21:00  2018-07-20 04:21:00    04:00:00
5   2018-07-20 17:00:00  2018-07-21 09:00:00    14:00:00
```

**Note:** If time_diff > 1 days, I already deal with that case.

**Question:** Should I build a function to do this or there are pandas build-in function to do this? Any help or guide would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @timgeb I convert it to datetime by using pd.to_datetime

Comment: Ok. I don't understand how you get to those expected valules. For example, the times in the first row are 4 hours apart, how do you get 2?

Comment: @timegeb if time exceeds 18.00 only use 18.00 to calculate. Sorry for not clear question.

Comment: Ok and in the second row both times are between 8 and 18. Why is their difference 0?

Comment: @timgeb Because it out of range from 18.00 - 8.00. Maybe it can be something else for indicating that this row is not in the range.

Comment: As your transformational rules are so complex, i suggest build a function and use apply. and it's not complicated to implement.

Comment: @Hsgao Thank for the suggestion, I guess I have to make function for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be a solution

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'time1': pd.to_datetime(['2018-07-16 16:00:00', '2018-07-11 08:03:00', 
                                             '2018-07-13 17:54:00', '2018-07-14 13:09:00', 
                                             '2018-07-20 00:21:00', '2018-07-20 17:00:00']),
                    'time2': pd.to_datetime(['2018-07-16 20:00:00', '2018-07-11 12:03:00', 
                                             '2018-07-13 21:54:00', '2018-07-14 17:09:00', 
                                             '2018-07-20 04:21:00', '2018-07-21 09:00:00'])})
time1_date = tmp.time1.dt.date.astype(str)
tmp['rule18'], tmp['rule08'] = pd.to_datetime(time1_date + ' 18:00:00'), pd.to_datetime(time1_date + ' 08:00:00')
# if stop exceeds 18:00:00, compute time difference from this hour 
tmp['time_diff_rule1'] = np.where(tmp.time2 > tmp.rule18, (tmp.time2 - tmp.rule18), (tmp.time2 - tmp.time1))
# rearrange the dataframe with your second rule
tmp['time_diff_rule2'] = np.where((tmp.time2 < tmp.rule18) & (tmp.time1 > tmp.rule08), 0, tmp['time_diff_rule1'])

  time_diff_rule1    time_diff_rule2  
0 02:00:00           02:00:00  
1 04:00:00           00:00:00  
2 03:54:00           03:54:00  
3 04:00:00           00:00:00  
4 04:00:00           04:00:00  
5 15:00:00           15:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think the last row should be 14:00:00.

Comment: why do you think that ?

Comment: If it in my case I guess it should be like this pd.to_datetime('2018-07-21 08:00:00')  - pd.to_datetime('2018-07-20 18:00:00') give 14:00:00

Comment: in your example the last row is `pd.to_datetime('2018-07-21 09:00:00') - pd.to_datetime('2018-07-20 17:00:00')` which is `16:00:00` but with `rule18` it becomes `15:00:00`

Comment: because if time exceed `08:00:00` it should be convert to `08:00:00`. Thank you for providing the example dataframe.